# What does Chicago Manual of Style say about publisher names?

Tags: citation-style

Sometimes books published by Eerdmans are misnamed in citations as “Wm. B. Eerdmans Publishing Company” or “William B. Eerdmans”, or just “Eerdmans”. What is the correct citation style according to the Chicago Manual of Style? Is there a general rule? Like “WB Eerdmans” use just plain “Eerdmans”. For Baker Publishing Group use “Baker”. For Zondervan Publishing House use “Zondervan”. Would that be an incorrect way of doing citations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 16th edition of the Chicago Manual of Style says, in relevant parts,

> ### Publisher's name
>
> **14.139** *Preferred form of publisher's name.* The publisher's name may be given either in full (e.g., as printed on the title page of the book) or in a somewhat abbreviated form. The shorter forms are preferred in most bibliographies (see 14.140). The form should, however, reflect the publisher's name at the date of publication, not the current name if the name has changed. Most publishers' names at the time of publication can be double-checked through any number of reputable sources, including the catalogs of the Library of Congress, WorldCat, and the *Books in Print* resources available through R. R. Bowker (see bibliog. 4.5).
>
> **14.140** *Abbreviations and omissible parts of a publisher's name.* In notes and bibliography, an initial *The* is omitted from a publisher's name, as are such abbreviations as *Inc.*, *Ltd.*, or *S.A.* following a name. *Co.*, *& Co.*, *Publishing Co.*, and the like are also omitted. Such corporate features of a publisher's name—often subject to many changes over the years—are far less important in leading a reader to the source consulted than the publication date, and attempting to include them will invariably lead to inconsistencies. A given name or initials preceding a family name, however, may be retained, as may terms such as *Sons*, *Brothers*, and so forth. *Books* is usually retained (Basic Books, Riverhead Books). The word *Press* can sometimes be omitted (for example, Pergamon Press and Ecco Press can be abbreviated to Pergamon and Ecco, but Free Press and New Press—whose names might be confusing without *Press*—must be given in full.) *Press* should not be omitted from the name of a university press because the university itself may issue publications independent of its press. The word *University* may be abbreviated to *Univ.* if done consistently.

Not surprisingly, the manual recognizes that it's more important a reader can find the cited work than it is to have a fully standardized way of writing the publisher's name. The William B. Eerdmans Publishing Company may well have used multiple names over the years, so it isn't obvious they were misnamed in the citations you list.

> For Baker Publishing Group use “Baker”. For Zondervan Publishing House use “Zondervan”. Would that be an incorrect way of doing citations?

"Publishing Group" and "Publishing House" both seem comparable with "Publishing Co.", so I believe they could be omitted. But I'd check that there isn't another publisher named "Baker" first.